# Appwrite - CRA App template with DI, onion-architecture

Tags: reactjs, oop, dependency-injection, onion-architecture, appwrite

I was tasked to implement software design of serverless `PWA` of crypto exchange platform which will receive payments from clients by using `MetaMask` (an Ethereum smart contract) and store withdrawal requests in an `AppWrite` collection. The main idea is simple: client is paying some coins online, taking a withdrawal ticket and getting money in the crypto bank office

[image: uniswap]

The mission of this platform is to help users send their money from different countries without person-to-person coin exchange. Just like in normal bank, but in coins. This means that in the future the code will become enterprise-like: `multiple http endpoints`, `multiple smart contracts` (maybe `custom ERC-20 token`), and `no one will want to rewrite it` (maybe [bsc-like](https://www.bnbchain.org/) `ethereum fork`). And all of It is `serverless` (as much as it can) and build on top of `cryptography`...

[image: clean-architecture]

The frontend must act not like a website, but a desktop app with complicated state management. To resolve this task, I need `OOP` with `composition of services` and `dependency injection`

> There is a think: using angular2 is not good enough because It must look great, not like a software from 200x. And It costs. A React sets of components looks great and developers are cheap enough

P.S. I googled, there are some libs like [inversifyjs](https://inversify.io/) but no one is applied to some starter kit on [Envato Market](https://themeforest.net/)

So, Is there any react app template or starter kit which will fit my task?

Answer (score 0):

I created a special CRA template which uses an `onion architecture` for global state management.

> The source code is published [at this GitHub repo](https://github.com/react-declarative/cra-template-appwrite)

Services inject each with a dependency provider and use [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/) to detect changes.

```html
├── lib
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── base
│   │   │   ├── AlertService.ts
│   │   │   ├── ApiService.ts
│   │   │   ├── ErrorService.ts
│   │   │   └── RouterService.ts
│   │   ├── db
│   │   │   └── TodoDbService.ts
│   │   └── view
│   │       └── TodoViewService.ts
│   ├── config.ts
│   ├── ioc.ts
│   └── types.ts
```

For example, a `TodoDbService` wraps interactions with [AppWrite](https://appwrite.io/) collection

```js
export class TodoDbService {

    private readonly apiService = inject<ApiService>(TYPES.apiService);

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    };

    findById = async (id: string) => {
        return await this.apiService.databases.getDocument<ITodoDocument>(
            CC_DB_TODO_DATABASE_ID,
            CC_DB_TODO_COLLECTION_ID,
            id,
        );
    };

    findByUserId = async (userId: string) => {
        return await this.apiService.databases.listDocuments<ITodoDocument>(
            CC_DB_TODO_DATABASE_ID,
            CC_DB_TODO_COLLECTION_ID,
            [
                Query.equal('userId', userId),
            ],
        );
    };

    create = async (payload: ITodoDto) => {
        return await this.apiService.databases.createDocument<ITodoDocument>(
            CC_DB_TODO_DATABASE_ID,
            CC_DB_TODO_COLLECTION_ID,
            'unique()',
            payload,
        );
    };

    update = async (id: string, payload: Partial<ITodoDto>) => {
        return await this.apiService.databases.updateDocument<ITodoDocument>(
            CC_DB_TODO_DATABASE_ID,
            CC_DB_TODO_COLLECTION_ID,
            id,
            payload,
        );
    };

    remove = async (id: string) => {
        return await this.apiService.databases.deleteDocument(
            CC_DB_TODO_DATABASE_ID,
            CC_DB_TODO_COLLECTION_ID,
            id,
        );
    };

};
```

As a benefit, you would not need to take database and collections ids to every component in UI

```js
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

const handleCreate = async () => {
    await ioc.todoViewService.create(title);
    reloadListSubject.next();
};

...

<Button onClick={handleCreate} ...
```

I think this starter kit is indispensable for startups at the time of MVP development because It helps to keep code as clean as possible

[image: screenshot]

**P.S. A DeFi-specific services has been written [in separate project](https://github.com/react-declarative/cra-template-solidity)**